# the \ac* command does not produce an abbreviation

Tags: acronyms

So I am finalising the TeX files for submission to IEEE. I have decided to use the **acro** package to make sure abbreviations appear properly. For some reason the output of \ac*{...} is not abbreviated.

Here is my header:

```
\documentclass[journal,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{acro}
```

Let's say I have defined the following acronym:

```
\DeclareAcronym{PET}{
    short=PET,
    long=positron emission tomography,
}
```

But for some reason using `\ac*{PET}` will systematically return "positron emission tomography (PET)". Example

```
some text

\ac*{PET}

some text

\ac*{PET}
```

It produces

[image]

Could it be because of a conflict with IEEEtran ?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the documented behaviour:

> If you use the starred variant an acronym will not be marked as used.

Use \ac{PET} instead:

```
\documentclass[journal,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{PET}{
    short=PET,
    long=positron emission tomography,
}

\begin{document}
some text

\ac{PET}

some text

\ac{PET}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes I just noticed, thanks!!